# React localStorage value resets after every refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

Whenever a new item is added to the list, the local storage is updated but if i refresh the page. The key remains but the value is reset to an empty array.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
    if (storedData) {
        setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    if (input) {
      const newItem = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: input };
      setData([...data, newItem]);
      setInput('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting the list to remain even after a refresh but the data does not persist.

Comment: do not use setItem of localStorage in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

These two useEffect hooks conflict each other

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
   if (storedData) {
     setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
   }
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify(data));
 }, [data]);
```

My solution is to create a new flag that check whether the data is loaded from localstorage or not

```
 const [isInit, setIsInit] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
   if (storedData) {
     setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
   }
   setIsInit(true)
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (isInit)
     localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify(data));
 }, [data, isInit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> localStorage value resets after every refresh

`setData` is asynchronous. The `localStorage.setItem` not. The function from the second `useEffect` will be called before `setData` from the first `useEffect` causing your `localStorage` to be overwritten with empty array, because in that moment `data` is `[]`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
    if (storedData) {
       setData(JSON.parse(storedData)); // will be called after second useEffect
    }
}, []);
```

Since `localStorage.setItem` is synchronous, I would suggest you to remove the first `useEffect` completely and move the logic directly to the `useState` hook to make it a *default* value.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
   const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
   if (storedData) {
     return JSON.parse(storedData);
   }

   return [];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the data variable has data in it, because the useEffect that watches data is called on the first render.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
    if (storedData) {
      setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length > 0) // <----- here
      localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify(data));
  }, [data]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    if (input) {
      const newItem = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: input };
      setData([...data, newItem]);
      setInput('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

better approach :

stakblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bhdhmy?file=src%2FApp.js

Removed Second useEffect: The second useEffect which was updating the local storage whenever data changed has been removed.

Added handleSetData Function: Introduced a new function called handleSetData that both updates the data state and saves this new data directly to local storage. This makes sure local storage stays in sync with state updates without the need for a useEffect.

Modified handleAddItem Function: Refactored the handleAddItem function to use the new handleSetData function, ensuring that when a new item is added, it is both added to the state and saved to local storage.

Added handleDeleteAll Function: Introduced a new function to clear all items. This function sets the data state to an empty array and also updates the local storage to reflect this change.

UI Additions: Added a new button to the component's return JSX that invokes handleDeleteAll when clicked, allowing users to clear all items.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
    if (storedData) {
      setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
    }
  }, []);

  //delete useEffect

  const handleSetData = (data) => {
    setData(() => data);
    localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  const handleAddItem = () => {
    if (input) {
      const newItem = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: input };
      handleSetData([...data, newItem]);
      setInput('');
    }
  };
  const handleDeleteAll = () => {
    handleSetData([]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      <button onClick={handleDeleteAll}>delete all</button>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: With the `data.length > 0` condition, the `data` will **not** be updated if user decides to remove all items, so local state and localStorage will be out of sync.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about deletion, but I will update my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove second the useEffect part and save the data in handleAddItem function.
Here is the full code you require.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('react-data-store');
    if (storedData) {
        setData(JSON.parse(storedData));
    }
  }, []);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    if (input) {
      const newItem = { id: crypto.randomUUID(), text: input };
      setData([...data, newItem]);
      setInput('');
      localStorage.setItem('react-data-store', JSON.stringify([...data, newItem]));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That should be worked.

Comment: The second `useEffect` is useful since it covers all of the changes in `data` and syncs it with `localStorage`. So in case if OP decides to add delete/edit actions to the list, he will now have to duplicate the code in each case.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But i think there are another way to handle delete/edit action to the list by making another function(manage localstorage) instead of useEffect.